# What is acceptable android memory consumption?

Tags: android, memory

My relatively small application for Android with nice graphics that consists mostly of 9patch drawables consumes about 10MB of the memory.

Do you think that it is OK? Or I should optimize it somehow? What is acceptable memory consumption for small applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get  approximate per-application memory limit for any device you can use [Activity member function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29)

```
 public int getMemoryClass ()
```

There is a 16/24MB memory limit for application running in android. [This](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/dad5be8ca26c1c51?pli=1) thread gives you more info..

[This](http://blog.gorges.us/2010/07/developing-apps-within-androids-16mb-memory-limit/) tutorial talks about some good memory management practices..

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule that small app should not take more than x mb memory. The default value of memory allocated by the Dalvik VM for each application is of 16 MB, using the Android 1.6 OS and higher. As long as your app is using memory under this limit, its perfectly fine.

If you really want to optmize your code, always make sure, you don't have any memory leaks in your app, and you are clearing your resources after use. That would only be the trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

10MB has been fine in my experience. The smallest Max Heap Size you are likely to come across is 16MB, and a lot of devices have higher than that now.

I'm not sure why the drawables are taking up so much ram though. Maybe try using a zipaligned APK if you are not already. The export signed APK wizard in eclipse is an easy way of getting one - the development builds are not generally zipaligned.