# Android App Memory Usage

Tags: android

I'm in the final stages of implementing a game for the Android platform and have been doing some memory profiling over the past few days. Although the app is running fine within the emulator environment, I am curious to know whether the memory it's using falls within an acceptable range.

While the app has been running, I've captured lines containing details such as the following in the output window:

```
GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 14K, 50% free 2939K/5831K, external 2210K/2581K, paused 170ms
GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 104K, 47% free 3142K/5895K, external 3710K/4633K, paused 263ms
GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 17K, 48% free 3106K/5895K, external 6362K/6398K, paused 104ms
GC_CONCURRENT freed 98K, 46% free 3225K/5959K, external 7462K/8042K, paused 8ms+8ms
GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 172K, 47% free 3269K/6087K, external 8023K/8042K, paused 183ms
```

As you can see, it typically runs with about 48% free memory.

My question is basically whether this is an acceptable amount of free memory?

Thanks,
Wayne.

Comment: The basic question is for who you have written your application. For efficient modern hardware or for wider community?

Comment: Take look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895534/what-is-acceptable-android-memory-consumption

Comment: I think the thing which I am unsure about is the amount of used/total memory which is being displayed in each of those log entries in my example. I had kind of assumed that I'd get at least 16MB in total displayed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is acceptable android memory consumption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895534/what-is-acceptable-android-memory-consumption)